# Error generating phpdoc with phing

Tags: php, jenkins, pear, phpdoc, phing

I'm configuring Jenkins for my project and I want to create phpdoc but it doesn't works.
I'm using phing and my server is with Debian.

What I've made :

- Install phpDoc

  ```
  pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor-beta
  ```
- Phing :

  ```
  <target name="phpdoc">
       <phpdoc2 destdir="${workspace}/app/docs" template="responsive">
           <fileset dir="./src">
               <include name="**.*.php" />
           </fileset>
       </phpdoc2>
   </target>
  ```

I'm getting this error :

```
    PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method phpDocumentor\Parser\Parser::setTitle() in /usr/share/php/phing/tasks/ext/phpdoc/PhpDocumentor2Wrapper.php on line 169
    PHP Stack trace:
    PHP   1. {main}() /usr/share/php/phing.php:0
    PHP   2. Phing::fire() /usr/share/php/phing.php:43
    PHP   3. Phing::start() /usr/share/php/phing/Phing.php:270
    PHP   4. Phing->runBuild() /usr/share/php/phing/Phing.php:170
    PHP   5. Project->executeTargets() /usr/share/php/phing/Phing.php:572
    PHP   6. Project->executeTarget() /usr/share/php/phing/Project.php:791
    PHP   7. Target->performTasks() /usr/share/php/phing/Project.php:818
    PHP   8. Target->main() /usr/share/php/phing/Target.php:321
    PHP   9. Task->perform() /usr/share/php/phing/Target.php:298
    PHP  10. PhingCallTask->main() /usr/share/php/phing/Task.php:260
    PHP  11. PhingTask->main() /usr/share/php/phing/tasks/system/PhingCallTask.php:158
    PHP  12. PhingTask->processFile() /usr/share/php/phing/tasks/system/PhingTask.php:150
    PHP  13. Project->executeTarget() /usr/share/php/phing/tasks/system/PhingTask.php:277
    PHP  14. Target->performTasks() /usr/share/php/phing/Project.php:818
    PHP  15. Target->main() /usr/share/php/phing/Target.php:321
    PHP  16. Task->perform() /usr/share/php/phing/Target.php:298
    PHP  17. PhpDocumentor2Task->main() /usr/share/php/phing/Task.php:260
    PHP  18. PhpDocumentor2Wrapper->run() /usr/share/php/phing/tasks/ext/phpdoc/PhpDocumentor2Task.php:147
    PHP  19. PhpDocumentor2Wrapper->parseFiles() /usr/share/php/phing/tasks/ext/phpdoc/PhpDocumentor2Wrapper.php:201
    Build step 'Invoke Phing targets' marked build as failure
```

It seems that phpDocumentor class is not found but I don't find why !

My include path is .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear and phpDocumentor is installed in /usr/share/pear folder.

Any ideas ?

Edit : 
I've created a simple test file :

```
    # cat test.php
    <?php
    $parser = new \phpDocumentor\Parser\Parser();
```

But I get this error :

```
    # php -f test.php
    PHP Fatal error:  Class 'phpDocumentor\Parser\Parser' not found in /var/www/test.php on line 2
    PHP Stack trace:
    PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/test.php:0
```

Why phpDocumentor seams to be not installed while I've :

```
pear info phpdoc/phpDocumentor
About pear.phpdoc.org/phpDocumentor-2.0.0
=========================================
Release Type          PEAR-style PHP-based Package
Name                  phpDocumentor
Channel               pear.phpdoc.org
[...]
Release Date          2013-08-03 06:08:35
Release Version       2.0.0 (stable)
API Version           2.0.0 (stable)
package.xml version   2.0
Last Modified         2013-08-06 08:17
Previous Installed    - None -
Version
```

Answer (score 1):

I've finally made it using exec command :

```
<target name="phpdoc" description="API Documentation">
     <exec command="phpdoc
        -d ${ws}/src
        -t ${builddir}/reports/doc/
        --template responsive
    " />
</target>
```

Less options and not really pretty but that works.

Answer (score 0):

Download the stable 1.4.4 (stable) - http://pear.php.net/package/PhpDocumentor/

Try maybe set the title:

```
<target name="phpdoc">
     <phpdoc2 title="Some Title" destdir="${workspace}/app/docs" template="responsive">
         <fileset dir="./src">
             <include name="**.*.php" />
         </fileset>
     </phpdoc2>
 </target>
```

Comment: Thanks but I get exactly the same error. I think it could be a pear autoloading configuration problem...

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that you are installing phpDocumentor 1.x but using a Phing task designed for phpDocumentor 2.x.

Comment: I've followed the install guide of http://www.phpdoc.org/ : 
        pear channel-discover pear.phpdoc.org
        pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor

Comment: I've tried to install phpDocumentor 1.x but same problem, so I came back to phpDocumentor 2.x.

Comment: My point is that it looks to me like the Phing Task you are using is one that's written for phpDocumentor 2.x (http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/appendixes/AppendixC-OptionalTasks.html#PhpDocumentor2Task).  But if you actually have phpDocumentor 1.x installed instead, you need to use Phing's Task that's written for it (http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/appendixes/AppendixC-OptionalTasks.html#PhpDocumentorTask).

Comment: However, I now think the more likely scenario is that the Phing's phpDocumentor2 Task may not be caught up with recent work in phpDocumentor 2.x's alpha/beta period.  It's entirely possible that class refactorings in phpdoc2 have made the Phing task inoperable.  That's only a guess though.